# If I default on a debt is the effect on my credit score the same regardless of the amount of debt?

Tags: united-states, credit-score, default

If I default on a debt is the effect on my credit score the same regardless of the amount of debt?

For example if I default on a few hundred dollars of medical debt would that effect my credit score less than defaulting on a many thousands of dollars of medical debt?

Comment: I think this is a good question, but your example is potentially different, a follow up would be about the type of debt (medical vs mortgage) not just amount.

Comment: @VBCPP Good point. I've edited the question to focus only on the amount of debt and not the type

Comment: I think this boils down to  "formulas for credit rating are proprietary, so few of us know and those may not be able to anser. The simple solution is "Don't!"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defaulting on a larger amount does lower your score more.  For a late payment, the size doesn't matter.

However in the scope of things that hardly matter. Any default or late payment regardless of size is serious.  A 30 day late payment for a $10 balance on a credit card can lower a good score by 50 points.  Any default will be much worse.

Bottom Line:  Any default should be avoided.  The "size"  making it a little worse is irrelevant.  Good rates and such are out the window either way.

Comment: Where are you getting that 50 points from? First hand experience? Some other source?